# Automatic check if input filled

Tags: php, html

There are 10 boxes in my website that I fill up based on my needs. From php code I prefer not to check them one by one like this. Instead of that I thought it would be a good idea to put check marks in each boxes and if I fill something in input field it should be checked so I can check however many checkboxes are filled and know how many boxes are filled.

```
if ($input1) {$total = "1"; 
    if ($input2) {$total = "2";
    }
}
```

Anybody knows how can I put automatically check into a checkbox when I start typing anything in it ? But it should be unchecked back if I delete what I wrote before sending it. Or if you guys have a better idea that would be nice also.

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you can just loop over your request parameter array?

Comment: I wanna do while but how can I check how many of them send without typing  it all over. I can put 2 whiles inside each other I guess.. Is that a good idea ?

Comment: " when I start typing anything in it" what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this in JavaScript. Basically if the number of input text is the same of the checkboxes then you could use this function for example:

```
function change() {

var input_lengths = document.getElementsByName("textArray[]");

for(var i= 0; i < input_lengths.length;i++) {

    if(document.getElementsByName("textArray[]").item(i).value != "") {

        document.getElementsByName("checkArray[]").item(i).checked = true;

    }

}
```

}

and your html could be:

```
    <input type="text" name="textArray[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="textArray[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="textArray[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="textArray[]" value="AAA" />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkArray[]" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkArray[]" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkArray[]" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkArray[]" value="" />

<input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:change()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you name your checkboxes as an array e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[2]" />
```

then you can loop through the array in php and check each one individually

Answer (score 2):

This is how i understood your problem:

- you have 10 text inputs
- you want to know how many of them contain actual input when they are submitted
- your idea was to assign a checkbox input to each text input so that the corresponding checkboxes are checked when an input has text and is unchecked when an input has no text

Something very quick and dirty. You might want to name you inputs with a square bracket, so that php interprets that parameter as an array. Then you can iterate over an array and if the values are set you can count.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['input'])) {
  $count = 0;
  foreach($_POST['input'] as $value) {
      if($value) {
         $count++;
      }
  }
  echo $count;
 }
?>
<form action="testinputs.php" method="post">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="input[]" value="" type="text">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to do that on the client side, than I'd take something like jQuery and look how many inputs on my page contain any text inside them.